Add an attribute to a WP Navigation Item with Children
I'm trying to add classes and other attributes only to the navigation links in a WP Navigation menu that have child items underneath them.  The goal is to create a mobile menu that has top level links that you can tap on to open (or close) the sub menu hidden beneath it.  I'd like to do it without having to create a custom walker menu-I think there's a simpler way.
I have gotten pretty close to the solution, thanks to this post:
WordPress menu how to add a class to only the parent a element?
But the solution provided ends up adding the class to ALL my top-level menu items, not just the ones with child items.
The code I'm using in my functions.php file:
/** Add class to parent menu items   **/
function add_classname_to_parent_nav_link($atts, $item) {

    // add class only on parent
    if($item->menu_item_parent == 0){
        $atts['onclick'] = 'twentytwentyoneExpandSubMenu(this)';
        $atts['class'] = 'sub-menu-toggle';
        $atts['aria-expanded']= 'false';
    }   
    return $atts;   
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_classname_to_parent_nav_link', 10, 2);

The HTML output I'm getting (edited down a bit for brevity):
<ul id="primary-menu-list" class="menu-wrapper">
    <li class=""><a href="https://example.com/home" onclick="twentytwentyoneExpandSubMenu(this)" class="sub-menu-toggle" aria-expanded="false">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#" onclick="twentytwentyoneExpandSubMenu(this)" class="sub-menu-toggle" aria-expanded="false">Projects</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="https://example.com/projects/child1">Child item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://example.com/projects/child2">Child item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="https://example.com/contact" onclick="twentytwentyoneExpandSubMenu(this)" class="sub-menu-toggle" aria-expanded="false">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

You can see the attributes are getting added to all the top-level items, even if they don't have a submenu beneath them.  WP automatically adds the class "menu-item-has-children" to li items that have child submenus.  Wrapping that requirement into my function might do the trick to eliminate the top level menu items that don't have children, but I'm not sure how to do that.  To be clear I'm trying to add these attributes to the a href link within the li element, not to the li element itself.
Any help is appreciated.
